# install4j prompting despite of running with -q and -varfile

Tags: install4j

I am running install4j binary on linux with -q and -varfile flags. It still prompts me for all the options.

```
./myInstaller.sh -q -varfile response.varfile -VskipRestore=true
Starting Installer ...
This will install Zephyr 4.1 on your computer.
OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]
```

I also verified that response.varfile gets copied into .install4j folder inside installation folder. Anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In unattended mode on unix, you get above exception (StackOverflowError). Documentation suggests to return null, which leads to following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.getProgressInterface(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following script works fine

```
UnattendedProgressInterface unattend = DefaultUnattendedProgressInterface();
return unattend;
```